# validationPost not defined discoveringMeteor tutorial

Tags: javascript, meteor, undefined

I am following "Discovering Meteor", currently I am in the 9th chapter.

When I am trying to visualize the errors which refers to:

- Please Fill in with a URL.
- Please Fill in with a headline.

I cannot visualize those errors .. I checked the web console and it says :

> ReferenceError: validatePost is not defined

Actually, I do not get it why, because I added :

```
validatePost = function (post) { 
 var errors = {};
    if (!post.title)  
        errors.title = "Please fill in a headline";  
    if (!post.url)    
        errors.url =  "Please fill in a URL";  
    return errors;
}
```

In posts.js which is under lib/collections.

The error occurs during a call in the client/templates/posts/post_submit.js

In fact , right now I cannot submit anything, neither edit nor delete any post.

I thought that firstly the flow control runs the 'lib' directory and then the rest of them..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I fixed it by copying the code of posts.js which is allocated in the github folder. The difference was that validatePost in github is outside Meteor.methods in contrast with what the tutorial said.(following step by step in this chapter).